# call RegQueryDWordValue to get office Excel Version using inno Setup installer

Tags: excel, installation, registry, inno-setup

How do I get installed Version of MS office Excel from registry using inno Script? i tried bellow code,it gives 'Key not found' but it exist

```
   function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
 var
  CurVer: Cardinal;
  key: string;

if RegQueryDWordValue(HKCR, 'Excel.Application\CurVer\','Default', CurVer) then
  begin
    // Successfully read the value
      MsgBox('Excel Version: ' + IntTOStr(CurVer),mbInformation, MB_OK);
    end else begin
      MsgBox('Key not found',mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Bear in mind there can be different versions installed. Check `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\XX.0\Excel` for the desired versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*changed RegQueryDWordValue to RegQueryStringValue*

```
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
 var
  CurVer: Cardinal;
  key: string;

begin


     //if RegQueryDWordValue(HKCR, 'Excel.Application\\CurVer\\','', CurVer) then
     if RegQueryStringValue(HKCR, 'Excel.Application\CurVer\','', key) then
  begin
    // Successfully read the value
      MsgBox('Excel Version: ' + key,mbInformation, MB_OK);
    end else begin
      MsgBox('Excel Not installed',mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Correct, that value is a `REG_SZ` type, not a `REG_DWORD`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing backslash.

Also, the `(Default)` value in RegEdit is the one with no name:

```
if RegQueryDWordValue(HKCR, 'Excel.Application\CurVer','', CurVer) then
```